# SOAP Exception handling in MVC Model Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have the web service call in Model class which is called from controller. Sometimes the web service throws exception(SOAP). Normal exceptions that happen at the controller level is handled in filterconfig by overriding  `OnException`. For SOAP exceptions that occur at the model level, they are not caught. How do I catch and handle these exceptions?

Exception handled in filter config:

```
 public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

When an unhandled exception occurs in an ASP.NET Web service, the Error event is not bubbled up to HTTP modules. Rather, it is intercepted by the ASP.NET runtime and a SOAP fault is returned to the client. To have an error logged in a Web service, you would need to create a SOAP Extension that listened for SOAP faults. You can learn more about creating SOAP Extensions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972353.aspx.